# How can I return only one resultset from a pivot query in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, resultset

I have the following T-SQL Pivot query.

```
SELECT AccountNumber, EventID, 
        CreateDate, [ITEMBOOK] AS ITEMBOOK, 
        [POSTER] AS POSTER
FROM
    (SELECT ProductID, Quantity, EventID,AccountNumber,CreateDate
    FROM #tmpStartupItems) ps
    PIVOT
    (
    SUM (Quantity)
    FOR ProductID IN
    ( [ITEMBOOK], [POSTER])
    ) AS pvt
```

When i run this it is returning both of the resultsets...is there  a way to limit it to return just the pivoted result set?

Seth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What "both resultsets"?  You should only get a single result set from a single SELECT statement, PIVOT or not.  And the SELECT in the subquery is not a second SELECT statement, it's a table expression (different thing), it should only return it's data to the larger calling SELECT statement.

Here is the BOL pivot example:

```
-- Pivot table with one row and five columns
SELECT 'AverageCost' AS Cost_Sorted_By_Production_Days, 
[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM
(SELECT DaysToManufacture, StandardCost 
    FROM Production.Product) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
AVG(StandardCost)
FOR DaysToManufacture IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS PivotTable
```

When I execute this agains the AdventureWorks database, I only get one result set, as expected.

If you are getting more then one resultset then either 1) this query is part of a larger stoered procedure that is executing another query and returning that other result set also (so change the stored procedure), OR 2) you are confusing something else (like PRINT statements) with being a result set, OR 3) there is something seriously wrong with your SQL Server or access tools.

Comment: You were right...the stored proc WAS returnig two select statements...I missed the first one.  

Seth